# Cannot see error that occured inside a julia @spawn method

Tags: asynchronous, error-handling, parallel-processing, stream, julia

I want to run multiple 'processes' in parallel in julia
For this, I use `@spawn`

However I don't see errors that occur in the spawned subprocess
The subprocess dies, but no error message

In a terminal, run julia and then, inside the julia vm(?), type the following:

```
function sub()
 println("1")
 error("2")
 println("3")
end
subproc = @spawn sub()
```

It prints '1', but nothing more

Is using `@spawn` the correct way? Where is the error output stream gone to? How can I see errors?

Thanks
Imran

Answer (score 1):

From your description I guess you didn't really launch more than 1 process, otherwise you will get "From worker X:  1" rather than just "1". You should use `julia -p X` or `addprocs(X)` to launch more processes.

To receive the error message or any other data from subprocesses, generally you need a `fetch` operation. Read [the manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/) for more details.

Here is an example that runs "actual" subprocess and displays the error message.

```
nprocs()<=1 && addprocs()
@everywhere function sub()
    println(1)
    error(2)
    println(2)
end
subproc = @spawn sub()
wait(subproc)
```

Comment: I ran your code, but also here I only get the print out from the first println command and do not see the error:
RemoteRef{ From worker 2: 1
Channel{Any}}(2,1,17)
after running @spawn sub()

Comment: @imran have you run `wait(subproc)`? What does it print after `wait(subproc)`?

Comment: wait(subproc) just prints: RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(2,1,17)

Comment: @imran That should be the returned value of `subproc = @spawn sub()`, `print(subproc)` could give the same output. Maybe you can try `fetch(subproc)`

Comment: I tried fetch(subproc), did not do anything
Do you see the error message?

Comment: @imran I got "ERROR: On worker 2:
2
 in sub at none:3
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:732
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:735
 in call_on_owner at multi.jl:778
 in wait at multi.jl:793"